# Problema con mi buscador AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

estoy haciendo un buscador que busque a medida que se escribe en tiempo real, y despliegue una lista de los **resutlados a medida que vas escribiendo en el input**:

Mi **menu.php**

```
<!-- As a heading -->
<nav class="col-md-12 d-flex justify-content-center navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1"><b>Buscador</b></span>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input id="key" name="key" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Buscar Usuario" aria-label="Search">
          <button  class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Buscar</button>
    </form>
</nav>
```

Mi **buscador.php** (la **vista**)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Buscador de personas</title>
    <?php include_once '../static/bootstrap_css.php' ?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php include_once '../static/menu.php' ?>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div id="suggestions"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>









    <?php include_once '../static/bootstrap_js.php' ?>


    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#key').on('keyup', function() {
            var key = $(this).val();        
            console.log(key);
            var dataString = 'key='+key;
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../clases/Search.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(data) {
                    //Escribimos las sugerencias que nos manda la consulta
                    $('#suggestions').fadeIn(1000).html(data);
                    //Al hacer click en alguna de las sugerencias
                    $('.suggest-element').on('click', function(){
                            //Obtenemos la id unica de la sugerencia pulsada
                            var id = $(this).attr('id');
                            //Editamos el valor del input con data de la sugerencia pulsada
                            $('#key').val($('#'+id).attr('data'));
                            //Hacemos desaparecer el resto de sugerencias
                            $('#suggestions').fadeOut(1000);
                            alert('Has seleccionado el '+id+' '+$('#'+id).attr('data'));
                            return false;
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Search.php** (fichero que recibe la peticion AJAX)

```
<?php
    include_once 'UsuarioHandler.php'
    $key=$_POST['key'];

    $uh = new UsuarioHandler();

    $html = '';
    $usuarios =  $uh->findLikeApellidos($key);

    if ($result) {

        foreach($usuarios as $usuario) {
            $html .= "<span>".$usuario['nombre']." <b>".$usuario['apellidos']. "</b></span>";
        }    
    }

    echo $html;
?>
```

**Error:**

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$key' (T_VARIABLE)

*Entiendo que el error esta al recibir la variable POST, pero no se porque*

---

**Aclaraciones..**
`$usuarioHandler` = es mi controlador que tiene difernetes funciones respecto a la tabla usuario.
`$usuarios =  $uh->findLikeApellidos($key);` = esto me devuelve un array de $usuarios (funciona **bien**, esto no es el problema)

Comment: la data se envia como clave : valor , cambialo a  `data: {key : "el_valor"}`

Comment: ; al final de la primera linea xD

Comment: @JackNavaRow lo he probado pero no va. Sigue sin reconocer la var $_POST

Comment: @jolsalazar tenias razon eso era jaja. Gracias

Comment: revisa tu archivo UsuarioHandler.php a ver si no le faltan comillas parentesis o llaves

Comment: Ya lo rvise, de hecho ya hice pruebas con el antes de seguir adelante (con el bsucador) para evitar arrastrar fallos.

Answer (score 1):

Viendo tu código, creo que el POST que recibe tu archivo **Search.php** espera un parámetro que se llame **key**. Podemos probar a enviarselo con lo siguiente:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "../clases/Search.php",
   data: { key: dataString},
   success: function(data) {
   ...
```

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar, o sea que cuando hago un post mediante AJAX las variables `$_POST['']` se envian en el atributo `data` en forma de `json`??

Comment: @josanangel te va a tocar hacer la prueba con postman porque al parecer el errror es netamente PHP, de esta forma ya la variable se envia, intenta hacer un var_dump de $_POST

Comment: acabo de encontrar el fallo, era una un punto y coma x

Comment: no, no funciona, ahora no da el error pero no funciona